# Python yagmail attachment not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, yagmail

I'm using [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail)-0.3.78 with Python 3.3 on Windows 8.1. I can get yagmail to send emails from my console but attachments just don't work.

```
yagmail.Connect('myemail@gmail.com','password').send('someguy@gmail.com', 'Test', 'This is a test', 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\mydoc.docx')
```

This returns an empty dict with no errors in the console. The email shows up with the right subject and body but no attachment. At first I thought my antivirus might be removing the attachment but there's nothing in the antivirus logs to suggest that it is.

p.s. Apparently there is no tag for yagmail, and I don't have the rep to create it.

**Edit-1:** Some progress(?)

```
contents = ['This is a test', 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\mydoc.docx']
yagmail.Connect('myemail@gmail.com','password').send('someguy@gmail.com', 'Test',contents)
```

...results in the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\yagmail-0.3.78-py3.3.egg\yagmail\yagmail.py", line 73, in send
    return self._attempt_send(addresses['recipients'], msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\yagmail-0.3.78-py3.3.egg\yagmail\yagmail.py", line 79, in _attempt_send
    result = self.smtp.sendmail(self.user, recipients, msg_string)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\smtplib.py", line 749, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 713-715: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Edit-2:** Thanks to PascalvKooten, see his answer below. Just a note on syntax...

```
yagmail.SMTP('mymail@gmail.com','password').send('someguy@gmail.com','Test1.2','This is a test','C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\mydoc.docx')
```

Does not work for me. However the below structure does work.

```
contents = ['This is a test', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\mydoc.docx']
yagmail.SMTP('mymail@gmail.com','password').send('someguy@gmail.com','Test1.2',contents)
```

Comment: What characters are at positions 713 to 715? Try changing the contents of mydoc.docx.

Comment: I may be misreading the code, but it looks to me like [yagmail doesn't support attachments](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail/blob/master/yagmail/yagmail.py#L216).

Comment: @SamuelTaylor I agree it looks like the attachment section doesn't do anything and/or is commented out. That's a bit of a shame, and also counter to the ReadMe file that has an example attaching an mp3 and png.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Are you able to confirm? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I had not noticed. The argument attachments is unused, however: you can send the file path in `contents` and it will work! Only limitation is that images will be displayed inline and cannot be attached. The rest will be attached. I'll have a look in a couple of hours, to see what's wrong if anything.

Comment: Ah, I think you have the old version, upgrade with pip install - U yagmail. (or pip3). Note that you'll have to use yagmail.SMTP instead of yagmail.Connect.

Comment: @SamuelTaylor My apologies. It is there when I thought I needed to do explicit attachments. At this point, only images would need to be explicitly attached (didn't implement it yet): at this point images will be embedded. Any other file paths will be attached.

Comment: @PascalvKooten no worries! I just gave the library a cursory glance; it's my bad. I should have looked more thoroughly. Thanks for making it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as the maintainer of the yagmail package: see this issue https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail/issues/5

It should be solved as of version 0.3.81.

Please update with `pip3 install -U yagmail`

I never tested this to work on windows, so that's my only uncertainty.

Comment: I've pip'd it, now on 0.4.84, and the attachment is working now, thank you. It is a bit strange though. The syntax `yagmail.SMTP('mymail@gmail.com','password').send('someguy@gmail.com','Test1.2','This is a test','C:\\Temp\\mydoc.docx')` does not work, even if you're explicit and use `attachment = blah..`. You have to put the body and attachment in a list first, and then put that list in the send method, like `cnts = ['This is a test','C:\\Temp\\mydoc.docx']` and then `yagmail.SMTP('mymail@gmail.com','password').send('someguy@gmail.com','Test1.2',cnts)`.

Comment: @I_do_python Indeed, attachments does not do anything. It's all about `contents` (using a list there of mixing actual text and attachments). Btw, as a bonus.... try omitting the password and use the keyring instead :) (I suppose it also works on windows).

Comment: Working perfectly fine on my windows machine now. I'm pulling the password from a secure database so no need to panic :-p. Thanks for the App!

Comment: @I_do_python Awesome, thanks for being a happy customer :P